# How do I add a hyperlink to a background image?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to add a hyperlink to this background image. Should I create a new class within the stylesheet? (When I attempted to call the new class, the image disappeared).

```
body{
  background-image:url('http://thehypebr.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/boundless-sem-branco-2.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  line-height:20px; font-size:14px;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
  margin:0
}
```

EDIT: Now there's whitespace on the top and bottom (created by the new div class?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place a div behind everything on the page, give it a background image, and then add an onclick handler to that div. But you can't hyperlink a background image.

You'd have to do something like:

```
<body>
    <div id='background' onclick='window.location.href="mynewurl"'>
        <!-- Rest of page goes here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Also, add `cursor: pointer` to the css for the background div so people know it's a link.

Comment: Thanks very much! But now there's that white space on the top bottom and the page menu itself. http://thehypebr.com/

Comment: Don't do `"onclick="window.location.href="http://boundlessny.com/clothing""` - do `"onclick='window.location.href="http://boundlessny.com/clothing'"` - i.e. nest single quotes inside double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You're using a `background-image` on the `body` tag. Assigning a hyperlink to it is impossible.

Also, whats stopping you from using it in an `img` tag? This seems like a semantically valid thing to do:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://thehypebr.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/boundless-sem-branco-2.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
```

But, if you must use it as a background image, than creating an additional class is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I can't tell you if this would be a valid solution, because I would have to see what you actually wanted to be a link.  If for example you wanted to make a link to the cream "Boundless" boxes in your background image I do have a work around.  It will be a pain to get it correct cross browser, but it's doable.

1. Make clear gif's the same size as your cream boxes
2. Put those images in something like this `<a href="#" class="bkg-link1"><img src="blank.gif" alt="Link Location" /></a>`
3. Use CSS to make the a tag a block element and place it over the cream boxes in the background image

I would of course clean up my code, it's a mess, but I am sure you can figure that out.  Just make sure to have descriptive alt tags for accessibility.

This isn't the best solution, that would be to take the "boundless" boxes out of the background image and place them instead of the blank gifs, but if you HAVE to do it for one reason or another, this option will work.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to change your html code a bit to do that.  You need to surround the image with a  tag, but you can't do that to the `<body>` tag, obviously.

** EDIT **  Since it's been pointed out my first answer is invalid HTML (thanks, and sorry), you can use a jquery approach like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").click(function(){
        window.location='http://www.yoururl.com';
    });
});
```

Comment: That's invalid HTML. You cannot have `div` in anchors

Comment: Like Yi said, you can't wrap a block-level element with an anchor tag. The only way to do it this way is to add a click handler to the div, as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with setting up an onClick method, is that you remove the anchor hint at the bottom left of the browser window, as well as any SEO that might be associated with the link.

You can accomplish this with just HTML/CSS:

```
<style>
   .background-div {
     background-image:url("/path/to/image.jpg");
     position:relative;
   }
   .href:after {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     content:"";
    }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="background-div">
   <a href="/a/url" class="href"></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

In this case, the relative positioning on background-div will keep the link contained to only that div, and by adding a pseudo element to the link, you have the freedom to still add text to the link (if necessary), while expanding the click radius to the entire background div.